# When rendering an Adaptive Card Html the data templating is not being used

Tags: c#, html, rendering, adaptive-cards

When using the C# HTML Adaptive Card rendered, when I include data for the template to rendered it is not utilised during the rendering process, using either the old synatx or newer syntax format.

Would anyone know if this is supported in by the .NET Html renderer, or is there some other approach that much be taken.

#### Rendering Result

You can see in the image below neither approach is picking up the data specified as part of the JSON card payload. The output should be

`Hello from, old syntax Ernest Hemingway, new syntax ${author.name}`

or

`Hello from, old syntax {author.name}, new syntax Ernest Hemingway`

[image]

#### Sample C#

```cs
public string Html(string cardJson)
{
    AdaptiveCardRenderer renderer = new AdaptiveCardRenderer();
    var version = renderer.SupportedSchemaVersion;
    var card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(cardJson);
    RenderedAdaptiveCard renderedCard = renderer.RenderCard(card.Card);
    // Get the output HTML 
    HtmlTag html = renderedCard.Html;
    return html.ToString(); ;
}
```

#### Sample Card Payload

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$data": {
    "author": {
      "name": "Ernest Hemingway"
    }
  },
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "text": "Adaptive Card Sample"
    },
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "weight": "Bolder",
              "text": "Hello from, old syntax {author.name}, new syntax ${author.name}",
              "wrap": true
            }
          ],
          "width": "stretch"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone needs to do this in the future, I found the solution, I needed to reference and use the AdaptiveCards.Templating package.

```cs
        public string Html(string cardJson)
        {
            var template = new AdaptiveCards.Templating.AdaptiveCardTemplate(cardJson);
            var cardPayload = template.Expand(new { author = new { name = "Noel" } });
            var card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(cardPayload);
            AdaptiveCardRenderer renderer = new AdaptiveCardRenderer();
            RenderedAdaptiveCard renderedCard = renderer.RenderCard(card.Card);
            HtmlTag html = renderedCard.Html;

            return html.ToString(); ;
        }
```